# Redefining operators c++

Tags: c++, class, matrix, operators

I tried to redefine + operator which was to sum 2 matrices and return the summation matrice in c++. But somehow it displays 0 all the time. What I'm missing? Here is my code. 
Also I've written this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class matrix{
    public:
        int a[100][100], n;
        matrix(int b[100][100], int n){
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int l=0; l<n; l++){
                    a[i][l]=b[i][l];
                }
            }
            n=n;
        }
        matrix(){}
        void matrix_input(int n){
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int l=0; l<n; l++){
                    cin >> a[i][l];
                }
            }
        }
        void matrix_print(int n){
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int l=0; l<n; l++){
                    cout << a[i][l] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }


} ;
matrix operator + (matrix x, matrix y){
            int s;
            int n=x.n;
            matrix sum;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int l=0; l<n; l++){
                    sum.a[i][l]=y.a[i][l]+x.a[i][l];

                }
            }
            return sum; 
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    matrix o;
    o.matrix_input(n);
    matrix c;
    c.matrix_input(n);
    matrix sum;
    sum=o+c;
    sum.matrix_print(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 ur code would not compile since it not include headers. i.e. it's not your code.

Comment: Can you show us what the input should look like?

Comment: It would compile with relevant headers, i.e. iostream, and putting in a using directive. We can assume he does this and is only showing us a sample expecting us to know the detail.

I can understand you gave this -1 under a "debug my code for me" post.

Comment: when I sum 1D matrices, the summation is 0. for 2d: 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your matrix constructor, `n = n` assigns the parameter to itself. You probably meant `this->n = n;`. However, it would be better for you to use the member-initialiser list:

```
matrix(int b[100][100], int n) : n(n)
{
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int l=0; l<n; l++) {
        a[i][l]=b[i][l];
    }
  }
}
```

And your `operator +` does not set `sum.n`.

**UPDATE**

`matrix_input()` does not modify the matrix's `n` member either. In other words, your class does not maintain its own invariants. Querying `x.n` inside `operator +` is then meaningless.

You should modify `matrix` so that its member `n` is always valid and reflects what's in the matrix. You can then drop the parameter `n` from `matrix_print()`.

And BTW, why do you call your member functions `matrix_something`? They are already in the scope of `matrix`. Just `input` and `print` would be fine.

Comment: Not sure if setting sum.n is important here.. hmm

Comment: @0A0D Not in this particular example, but when viewed generally, it leads to a matrix with a random value of `n`.

Comment: I think I was not using this constructor. when creating summation matrix.

Comment: @Angew: Right, if you are only printing it then fine. But it could lead to problems down the road

Comment: @filemonster But you are using `x.n` inside `operator +`, and `n` is never set.

Comment: oh I thought matrix_something would be more clear to distinguish.

Comment: @filemonster It's just syntactic noise, really. `std::vector` also doesn't have functions `vector_push_back`, `vector_add`, `vector_clear`, ...

Answer (score 2):

Your main error is in the line `n=n`, which is a self-assignment.

As you can guess this is pretty much a no-op when n is an integer (and should be most of the time). You mean `this->n = n`;

(better way is to not clash the naming but that small fix will work. You also need to fix operator+ to assign `sum.n = n;`

The local `n` parameter takes precedence over the class member so you need `this->n` to qualify the class member.

Incidentally your matrices are quite large (10,000 ints) so are expensive to copy. So your `operator+` overload would be more efficient if it took its parameters as const references.

Presumably `n` is a logical size, as physically your matrix is always 100 * 100. Your default constructor though should at least initialize `n` to 0 or subsequent behaviour trying to read this matrix would be undefined. You should possibly put in assertion checks when reading what might be beyond the bounds of your matrices. (Your operator+ could check that both have the same dimension).

If you want to use "dynamic" sizing, so you only use the memory resources you are going to actually use for your matrix, you would implement it a bit differently. I guess that would be a more advanced exercise for your level.

Incidentally it "printing 0 all the time" is random as the behaviour you should get is actually undefined, as `x.n` (and `sum.n` in the addition) is an uninitialised variable that you are then reading.

Comment: oh I think I found my problem here. x.n

Comment: You need to set this->n in the constructor and sum.n in operator+